# Never do the same "with "my smile or never do the same "to" my smile which one is correct

Tags: grammar

[image]
I have posted a image of my quote 
Please correct me if you found any mistake

Answer (score 1):

Either strikes me as correct. 
I think applying the verb 'steal' here can be taken as something that is done to the heart, or in stealing it you are doing something with the heart.

I think think the former instance (to) strikes one as more correct grammatically, but the latter is a valid usage because of the common phrase "What have you done with my (noun)?" which is used in any context where someone has altered or moved something of yours.

Comment: Hello, Robert. Unsupported answers tend to come across as (and may be) mere opinion; ' ... strikes me as correct' just reinforces this. My opinion is that 'with' is more idiomatic here, to make the metaphor less clinical-sounding, but frequencies of use should be checked.

Answer (score 0):

It seems right to me in this context to use the word "with". Or you could say:

> You will never do the same to me / him.

Here you have a better explanation: [“do to” vs. “do with”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/113889/do-to-vs-do-with)

Comment: Hello, lumadev. The ELL analysis doesn't cover 'do the same with' = 'subject to the same fate' sense.

Comment: I've added a relevant answer at ELL.